# accessing database created in mysql via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, yii, phpmyadmin

Does the mysql program running under the linux terminal look at the same databases as the phpmyadmin tool?

The problem that I have is that using "show databases;" in mysql in the terminal I can see a database I created, but in the phpmyadmin tool it does not show up in the list of databases.

Consequently my php programs cannot find the database (I am trying to get started with the yii2 cms framework).

How is it possible that the phpmyadmin and the mysql command show different databases? They are both logged in as the same user. ie..
"select user();" executed in the mysql command and in phpmyadmin both say: root@localhost.

Comment: show db config of your Yii app

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin uses the local host to connect with mysql, so you have to check if you have an apache server running and connected with phpmyadmin... The terminal works when you install mysql... So if you have not configured the apache server this will heappen.

Comment: I can browse to "localhost/phpmyadmin" using firefox. Does that mean that the apache server is running and connected to phpmyadmin? But I still cannot see the same list of databases as I can see with mysql.